# Openshift : SocketException (Permission denied) using Spring and embedded Ldap server

Tags: openshift-online-2, springframework, apache-ds

I'm facing the following error when I try to deploy my app which initializes an embedded Ldap server using Spring and ApacheDS on port 33389:

```
2014-10-20 12:55:22,933 ERROR (ContextLoader.java:331) - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.apacheDirectoryServerContainer': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Server startup failed
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1083)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1880)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Server startup failed
        at org.springframework.security.ldap.server.ApacheDSContainer.start(ApacheDSContainer.java:180)
        at org.springframework.security.ldap.server.ApacheDSContainer.afterPropertiesSet(ApacheDSContainer.java:130)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
        ... 25 more
Caused by: org.apache.directory.shared.ldap.exception.LdapConfigurationException: Failed to bind an LDAP service (33389) to the service registry. [Root exception is java.net.SocketException: Permission denied]
        at org.apache.directory.server.ldap.LdapServer.startNetwork(LdapServer.java:528)
        at org.apache.directory.server.ldap.LdapServer.start(LdapServer.java:394)
        at org.springframework.security.ldap.server.ApacheDSContainer.start(ApacheDSContainer.java:178)
        ... 28 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:444)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:436)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:214)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
        at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.NioSocketAcceptor.open(NioSocketAcceptor.java:251)
        at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.NioSocketAcceptor.open(NioSocketAcceptor.java:48)
        at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoAcceptor.registerHandles(AbstractPollingIoAcceptor.java:523)
        at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoAcceptor.access$200(AbstractPollingIoAcceptor.java:65)
        at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoAcceptor$Acceptor.run(AbstractPollingIoAcceptor.java:407)
        at org.apache.mina.util.NamePreservingRunnable.run(NamePreservingRunnable.java:64)
```

I guess Openshift doesn't allow me to bind arbitrary port but I wonder if I am actually in the situation in which I have to setup a port forwarding as mentionned in this post:
https://blog.openshift.com/getting-started-with-port-forwarding-on-openshift/

Any suggestion or tips are welcome...

Comment: Is the LDAP server trying to bind to localhost instead of the correct ip address?